# Extract native (Android) View from ReadableMap (React Native)

Tags: java, android, react-native

Could somebody please link me some documentation or sample code on extracting a `<View>` hierarchy in native Java (Android) code? It is currently stored in a `ReadableMap` entry, but there is no `ReadableMap.getView("<key>")`? How can I accomplish this?

Sample code on what I current have (and what I'm trying to achieve commented out) below:

#### module.java

```
ReadableMap dictionary;
// View view = dictionary.getView("view");
```

#### index.android.js

```
dictionary = {
    view: (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Text>Hello, world!</Text></View>)
};
```

Comment: Did you find any answer? Is it at least possible?

Comment: Nope, sorry :-( I actually went through the React Native source code and it doesn't seem to support such a thing.